# Android matrix aligning

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas

I want to make the following canvas:
Draw N bitmaps at given points, but each bitmap should be rotated at a random angle.

I try something like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<point_count;i++){
        star_matrix[i] = new Matrix();

        Random rand2 = new Random();
        int degree = rand2.nextInt(45);  

        star_matrix[i].postRotate(degree); 
        star_matrix[i].postTranslate(level.points[i].x - star1_size/2, level.points[i].y-star1_size/2);
    }
```

Then I create a bitmap

```
star1  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star1_small);
star1  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(star1, star1_size,star1_size, true);
```

and draw all in cycle:

```
for(int i=0;i<point_count;i++){
    canvas.drawBitmap(star1, star_matrix[i], gradPaint);
}
```

And all the bitmaps miss their right position. All are shifted to different places.

For example, this code without matrixes draws everythong as it should be(but without rotation)

```
for(int i=0;i<point_count;i++){
   canvas.drawBitmap(star1, level.points[i].x - star1_size/2,  level.points[i].y-star1_size/2, pathPaint);
}
```

How to solve Matrix problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose changing reordering of the following lines should help:

```
    star_matrix[i].postTranslate(level.points[i].x - star1_size/2, level.points[i].y-star1_size/2);
    star_matrix[i].postRotate(degree);
```

Because the order of rotation and translation is important.